# Ryzen 1700 boost does not work

Tags: 17.04, amd-processor

I just finished building my new PC, containing:

```
Ryzen 7 1700
AsRock AB350M Pro4 (Bios 3.00)
2x8GB HyperX RAM 2667
Samsung Evo 960
Ubuntu MATE 17.04 (kernel 4.12 currently)
```

It seems that my Ryzen does not want to boost. As far as I know, it should boost to 3.7Ghz on one core, and if all cores are busy, it should be 3.2Ghz for all cores.

But no matter what I try, the CPU only clocks to 3Ghz. Down clocking works (1.55Ghz & 2.7Ghz), but even when compiling large project with -j 16 and all cores are under full load, it's only @ 3Ghz:

```
watch -n 1 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"'

cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The Base Clock Speed is 3GHz (the  Max Turbo Core Speed being 3.7GHz, as you posted), according to AMD: https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-1700 . I don't know where the 3.2GHz figure comes from. If you noticed higher speeds in Windows that could be due to OC.

Comment: The Ryzen 1700 has 3GHz base, 3.2Ghz all-core, and 3.7Ghz single core boost. This can be read on various sites all over the net. However, it might be, that the boost frequency is not reported to the OS, or the kernel does not recognize it.

I also never saw 3.7Ghz even when I put a single core under full load.

Comment: Please feel free to [edit] your question and add one or a couple of links to those sources.

Comment: AMD Turbo Boost was not working even in Piledriver CPUs. I am using Ubuntu on AMD FX6300 since December 2012 (first it was 12.04, then 14.04 and now 16.04) and never ever any CPU tool on Ubuntu showed that CPU has more than base clock (3.5GHz). Even with ver good cooler, and under extreme load, the clock is fixed at 3.5GHz.